# should i use sequence ids for database or uuid_short()?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, uuid

i want to implement facebook like id's for user, pages, photo, album, event, comments and like. they all are unique id's and most of them can be accessed from http://facebook.com/{object_id}

and to like or comment any object, you just simple do http://facebook.com/{object_id}/comment or likes.

mysql implementation on sequence: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/04/02/stored-function-to-generate-sequences/

mysql doc on uuid_short(): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short

what are advantages and disadvantages for using sequence?

btw if i were to implement sequence, i would choose BIGINT for the field type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InnoDB, a numeric value wins over a UUID value every time.

Assuming you make this value the primary key, it will be clustered. Strictly increasing numeric values are far superior to UUIDs.

For more, see these answers [Mysql How do you create a clustered index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779138/mysql-how-do-you-create-a-clustered-index) and the subsequent links. And this [Google books link](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=mysql%20clustered%20index%20uuid&source=bl&ots=COVPApqH1Q&sig=p7ujoLNqwbc3VTHa636BJAAp8YQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AjN2UcyvNMHbPdX1gYgF&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=mysql%20clustered%20index%20uuid&f=false). And [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322/what-are-the-drawbacks-with-using-uuid-or-guid-as-a-primary-key)

Note: the same reasoning applies to SQL Server and Sybase too

Comment: i dont mean to use UUID, but UUID_short(), which is numeric too.

Comment: it has some conditions, if one condition fails, the uniqueness will fail too. click on the above link to read all the conditions on it.

Comment: @Basit: I saw that, but it appears to be an edge case when you change the system time. You can avoid this by using UTC always.

Comment: this is little off-topic, but i was wondering if you knew how google+, facebook, pinterest.. saved there id's in DB?

Comment: I don't sorry. Never needed to look into it