# MySQL table with 50+ million rows - how to speed up searching using indexes?

Tags: mysql

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_bussines (
bussines_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (bussines)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7059415 ;
```

My SELECTs on this table will have WHERE clauses with one or more of 'name', 'searched on. It will get slow.

Comment: Please, add some example of query and an EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0):

You can created a clustered index on Name. Please see this question for more information [Mysql How do you create a clustered index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779138/mysql-how-do-you-create-a-clustered-index)