# what is meaning of clustered index in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have confusion in clustered index in database concept.
I completely read about indexing. So i understood the indexing.
But i don't know what is the proper meaning of clustered index.
Can any one help what is clustered index?

Comment: Have you search about this?

Comment: [What do Clustered and Non clustered index actually mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean) - being a possible duplicate. Or [Mysql How do you create a clustered index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779138/mysql-how-do-you-create-a-clustered-index)

Comment: Yeah, But I did not get concept properly. Can you help me out on this?