# Configure MySQL Table to Order by UNIQUE Index

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table with these fields:

```
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ReleaseDate DATETIME(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT "1970-01-01"
```

The default ordering of this table is by the `Id` because it is the primary key. When I drop the `Id` column and make the `Name` the primary key the table is ordered alphabetically, which is what I want.

With the `Id` as the primary key and the `Name` is a `UNIQUE` index the table continues to remain ordered in order of increasing `Id`. I know I can use `ORDER BY Name` when displaying the table but is there a way to configure the table itself to always remain in alphabetical name order, and completely disregard the order of the Id column?

Comment: Can you please tag appropriately! You say MySQL.. but have SQL-server etc in your tags..

Comment: Take a look at this to see if it helps : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142979/ordering-of-table-is-based-on-clustered-index-or-non-clustered-primary-key

Comment: two posts you need to check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779138/mysql-how-do-you-create-a-clustered-index     AND        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824928/how-to-sort-a-mysql-table-in-a-permanent-way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason in SQL you should ever depend on the physical order of the database. Relational tables are conceptually more like unordered sets than ordered lists. Assuming a certain physical order may lead to unpredictable results.

If you always want an ordered version of your table available, you can use a view.

```
CREATE VIEW orderedView AS
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY myColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

In a relational database generally a table is ordered physically by the PRIMARY KEY. With this, the performance of queries is increased. So, if you want that your table stay ordered by "name", you must declare "name" like your primary key. If it is not really necessary, you should create a view.