# What happens with Oracle Table with no primary key

Tags: mysql, oracle

In MySql, if no primary key is defined for a table, MySQL associates a default clustered index with it which functions like a primary key.
What is the case with Oracle table having no primary key ?

Comment: your first statement is not exactly correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779138/mysql-how-do-you-create-a-clustered-index An Oracle database uses heap tables by default; if present, Oracle database always uses the primary key as the clustering key.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL (or rather innodb, which is the storage engine) does not store data the way Oracle normally does.

- in MySQL (innodb), data is always stored in what is called a "clustered index". Even though it is called an index, *all* the data is stored there, not just the indexed columns. The data is stored in the order of the indexed column(s). If there is no appropriate primary or unique key, a synthetic key is used.
- in the Oracle database, by default a table is stored as a *heap*, meaning rows are not stored in any particular order. Heap tables can exist without an index of any kind.
- Oracle allows us to define *index organized tables* which work like the MySQL tables, but they must have a primary key.

So bottom line, without a primary (or non-null unique) key, the only way to uniquely identify a row in an Oracle heap table is the ROWID pseudocolumn. However, an index on ROWID is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle nothing happens with a table with no primary key. There's no key or index created automatically.